# critical error thrown while running command "doctrine:migrations:migrate". Message: "An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver"

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, drupal, symfony1

I am working with **Symfony**.
When i use `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`
I am getting

> An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver

I am using XAMPP & Windows 11

I have uncommented the `extension=pdo_mysql` in php.ini

[image]

Comment: Is DATABASE_URL correctly set?

Comment: Please add info about your php config "php -i | grep mysql" for example